# SQL Server Management Studio Console location

Tags: ssms

I was told to look for SSMS console,
but I have no idea where is it?
Can someone tell me where it is located?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/59397791-dab9-40ce-a048-cf4598d0836b/sql-server-2008-management-console-where-is-it

Comment: Hi, it didnt't gave me the info that I needed

Comment: Ok,  what info do you need.  I assume that you have SQL Server Management studio, installed.  But if not,  you will need to install it either from the SQL dvd (client tools) or you could download an express edition.  http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8961

Comment: I backup a master database in a single user mode.
After which, I restore it using single user mode too.
When i execute the statement, it's stated that restore successfully.
however, when I check go to report > back up and restore event, no restore data was being seen(it stated that you have not done any restore).
I check onto my lab sheet, i was told to navigate master database in SSMS console..
I do not know where it is. 
Could u help me out?
Thanks.

Comment: could you help with this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20703711/restoring-and-verifying-of-master-database-in-ssms